# Ajax form submit and errors to appear in template in JSON format (django)

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have a django site:

js

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

    $.getJSON( post_url , form_data,function( response ) {
        //iterate json response
        $.each( response, function(key, val) {
            $("#msgSubmit").append( val + "<br />"); //append results to element
        });
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def contact_form(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = {
            'success': True,
        }
        status = 200
    else:
        data = {
            'success': False,
            'errors': form.errors.get_json_data(),
        }
        status = 400
    return JsonResponse(data, status=status)
```

html

```
<form id="contactForm" method="get" action="{% url 'contact-form' %}">
...
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="msgSubmit"></div>
```

When I submit the form:
If there is no validation errors, I get 'true' appearing at #msgSubmit.
If there is an error, I get nothing.

I want JSON errors to appear at #msgSubmit.

Returned JSON is something like:

```
{"success": false, "errors": {"email": [{"message": "Please enter your email", "code": "required"}]}}
```

I've tried

```
alert(response);
```

but it doesn't alert. It seems JSON is not returned during ajax request.

This code alerts "fail".

```
$.getJSON( post_url , form_data)
    .done(function( response ) {
        alert(response);
        //iterate json response
        $.each( response, function(key, val) {
            $("#msgSubmit").append( val + "<br />"); //append results to element
        });
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Handle your errors here
        alert("fail");
    });
```

So it appears $.getJSON() has failed.

The following:

```
$.getJSON( post_url , form_data)
    .done(function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        //iterate json response
        $.each( response, function(key, val) {
         $("#msgSubmit").append( val + "<br />"); //append results to element
    }   );
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Handle your errors here
      alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

alert dumps the expected JSON string:

```
{"success": false, "errors": {"name": [{"message": "Please enter your name", "code": "required"}], "subject": [{"message": "Please enter your subject", "code": "required"}], "email": [{"message": "Please enter your email", "code": "required"}], "budget": [{"message": "Please enter your budget", "code": "required"}], "message": [{"message": "Write your message", "code": "required"}]}}
```

I can use this logic by putting stuff inside .done when the form has no validation errors, and inside fail when there is a validation error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery's Ajax method such as `done`, `fail`, etc. More detail [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jqxhr-object).

```
$.getJSON( post_url , form_data)
.done(function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    //iterate json response
    $.each( response, function(key, val) {
        $("#msgSubmit").append( val + "<br />"); //append results to element
    });
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Handle your errors here
});
```

Comment: tried that but still alert(response) gives nothing.

Comment: Where you put that script? inside fail callback? it should be alert(jqXHR. responseText);. I just updated the answer, please take a look

Comment: {"success": false, "errors": {"name": [{"message": "Please enter your name", "code": "required"}], "subject": [{"message": "Please enter your subject", "code": "required"}], "email": [{"message": "Please enter your email", "code": "required"}], "budget": [{"message": "Please enter your budget", "code": "required"}], "message": [{"message": "Write your message", "code": "required"}]}}

Comment: alert gives the json dump above. but alert() was placed inside fail.

Comment: i think success logic is when the form has no validation errors. and, if there is a validation error, then it is fail (inside ajax request). thanks for your help!